# How to set function converted from number into html span tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need help with the last line in this. I need to take the current month,
picked from the getMonthText var and have it be in the

```
<h1><span id="month_year">&nbsp;</span></h1>
```

Beginning of code.
My issue is at the bottom
This part turns the month number into a name.

```
    var getMonthText = function(currentMonth) {
        if (currentMonth === 0) { return "January"; }
        else if (currentMonth === 1) { return "February"; }
        else if (currentMonth === 2) { return "March"; }
        else if (currentMonth === 3) { return "April"; }
        else if (currentMonth === 4) { return "May"; }
        else if (currentMonth === 5) { return "June"; }
        else if (currentMonth === 6) { return "July"; }
        else if (currentMonth === 7) { return "August"; }
        else if (currentMonth === 8) { return "September"; }
        else if (currentMonth === 9) { return "October"; }
        else if (currentMonth === 10) { return "November"; }
        else if (currentMonth === 11) { return "December"; }
    };
```

After that and some other code
......
This is the problem area

```
    $("#month-year").html(getMonthText);  <-- set it to the html ***This is the part I'm having trouble with, even though it should be simple.
```

Thanks for any/all help.

Comment: should it not be `$("#month-year").html(getMonthText(number))`

Comment: That if else chain could be removed entirely in exchange for an array with the month number being the index, and the month name the value.

Comment: In your function you could put all your month names in an array and simply return `monthNames(currentMonth)`. A bit simpler.

Comment: Carsten - I tried that as well ... still not showing up in the <h1> span tag

Comment: @Jammie `month_year` and `month-year`

Comment: Wow! Thanks, Carsten. That did it. I didn't notice the "-" instead of "_". You're awesome!

Answer (score 2):

Ouch! This is not the way to be doing this. Just set up an array of month names and get the right name via its index. No `if`/`else if` needed.

Also, don't forget the `()` and the argument value after your function name so that you actually invoke the function.

Additionally, your HTML `id` uses an underscore, while your JQuery reference to the element attempts a hyphen. They must match up.

Finally, don't use the `.html()` method if you aren't passing any HTML to the element. It causes the HTML parser to parse the string and if there isn't any HTML in the string, it's a waste of resources. When you have plain text, use the `.text()` method, which doesn't do any parsing on the string.

```js
var months = [
  "Januaray", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];

function getMonthText(currentMonth) {
  return months[currentMonth];
}

$("#month_year").text(getMonthText(6));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1><span id="month_year"></span></h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the value your passing to the function: `getMonthText(2)` the `(value)` is missing.

You also have a type error. your html id is `month_year` but your jquery is `month-year`

```js
var getMonthText = function(currentMonth) {
  if (currentMonth === 0) {
    return "January";
  } else if (currentMonth === 1) {
    return "February";
  } else if (currentMonth === 2) {
    return "March";
  } else if (currentMonth === 3) {
    return "April";
  } else if (currentMonth === 4) {
    return "May";
  } else if (currentMonth === 5) {
    return "June";
  } else if (currentMonth === 6) {
    return "July";
  } else if (currentMonth === 7) {
    return "August";
  } else if (currentMonth === 8) {
    return "September";
  } else if (currentMonth === 9) {
    return "October";
  } else if (currentMonth === 10) {
    return "November";
  } else if (currentMonth === 11) {
    return "December";
  }
};
$("#month_year").html(getMonthText(2));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1><span id="month_year">&nbsp;</span></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function works, you just called it wrong way. See example:

```js
var getMonthText = function(currentMonth) {
    if (currentMonth === 0) { return "January"; }
    else if (currentMonth === 1) { return "February"; }
    else if (currentMonth === 2) { return "March"; }
    else if (currentMonth === 3) { return "April"; }
    else if (currentMonth === 4) { return "May"; }
    else if (currentMonth === 5) { return "June"; }
    else if (currentMonth === 6) { return "July"; }
    else if (currentMonth === 7) { return "August"; }
    else if (currentMonth === 8) { return "September"; }
    else if (currentMonth === 9) { return "October"; }
    else if (currentMonth === 10) { return "November"; }
    else if (currentMonth === 11) { return "December"; }
};

$("#month-year").text(getMonthText(0));
```

```html
<div id="month-year"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```